# Trouble with having clause

Tags: mysql, having

My tables,  borrower:

```
+----------+---------+
| name     | loan_id |
+----------+---------+
| Adams    | L16     |
| Curry    | L93     |
| Hayes    | L15     |
| Jackson  | L14     |
| Jones    | L17     |
| Smith    | L11     |
| Smith    | L23     |
| Williams | L17     |
+----------+---------+
```

loan:

```
+---------+-------------+--------+
| loan_id | branch_name | amount |
+---------+-------------+--------+
| L11     | Round Hill  |    900 |
| L14     | Downtown    |   1500 |
| L15     | Perryridge  |   1500 |
| L16     | Perryridge  |   1300 |
| L17     | Downtown    |   1000 |
| L23     | Redwood     |   2000 |
| L93     | Mianus      |    500 |
+---------+-------------+--------+
```

I wish to find the maximum loan taken by the customer.

I was partially successful with the query:

```
select name, max(amount) 
from loan, borrower 
where borrower.loan_id=loan.loan_id;
```

Result:

```
+-------+-------------+
| name  | max(amount) |
+-------+-------------+
| Adams |        2000 |
+-------+-------------+
```

But it is taking the name from the first row and finding the maximum amount and printing the result. So I used the `having` clause like this:

```
select name, amount
from loan, borrower 
where borrower.loan_id=loan.loan_id 
having max(amount)=amount;
```

But I get an empty set.

Comment: Why are you using a having clause? What do you try doing? How come you're not grouping by customer?

Comment: Do you want the maximum loan per customer? Or the maximum loan and the customer who has it? The 'having' clause is a 'where' clause  for 'groups' defind by the 'group by' clause..

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by` customer and get the `max` amount from the joined `loan` table.

This query is very similar to your first attempt, but the difference is in the `group by` clause. This causes the query to return one row per customer name (name is in group by). The `max` (and `sum` too, in my example) are calculated per 'group', so per name in this case.

In your query, you didn't have `group by`, so the `max` is determined (*aggregated*) over all rows. Many other databases wouldn't even execute your query, because they feel a field should either be specified in `group by` or it should be called in an aggregation function like `min`, `max`, or `sum`. MySQL is a bit <strike>silly</strike> different, because it just picks any of the customer names to display.

```
select
  b.name,
  max(l.amount) as Highest,
  sum(l.amount) as Total
from
  Borrower b
  inner join Loan l on l.loan_id = b.loan_id
group by
  b.Name
```

Of course, it would be better if a customer also has an ID. After all, you're likely to get two customers both named Smith.

Comment: Can you please explain the query. I can understand it more better

Comment: _“The query throws error”_ – good thing you decided to keep that error a secret – otherwise people might be able to actually help you with that …

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to get the loan with the maximum amount and the customer who has it, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT b.name, l.loan_id, l.amount 
FROM borrower AS b
INNER JOIN loan AS l ON b.loan_id = l.loan_id
ORDER BY l.amount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The query creates a set of all loans along with their associated customer, orders this set by `amount` in descending order and returns the topmost record, i.e. the record having the maximum amount.

If more than one loans have the same maximum amount and you want the data of *all* of these loans returned, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT b.name, l.loan_id, l.amount 
FROM borrower AS b
INNER JOIN loan AS l ON b.loan_id = l.loan_id
WHERE l.amount IN (SELECT MAX(amount)
                   FROM loan )
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2241d8/1)

Comment: Can you please explain what you did. I can understand it better that way